# how "http://ghost.org/" html/css works

Tags: css, html, web

on http://ghost.org/ page there is section for logos.
If we see the html source of this section

```
<div class= "logos">
   <section class="logos-section">
       <span class="logo">...</span>      ---- Ref1
       ...
   </section>
   <section class="logos-section">
       <span class="logo">...</span>      ---- Ref2
        ...
   </section>
<div>
```

Then why Ref2 image is not just below the Ref1 ?
why it is shifted by "s1" amount ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to find out how it does it or why it does it?

Comment: It is just centralized, can't you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in your screenshot at the very bottom right.

```
text-align:center;
```

And since `.logo` has `display:inline-block;` it's affected by `text-align`

Comment: What is the best resource to learn all this stuff... what property affect what property...

Comment: @user2410148 Sorry, I don't know what's currently the best resource for newcomers. I just know stuff from years of experience.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "how do they center the logos?"

They are using `text-align: center;` on the `section` element, and `display: inline-block;` on the `spans`.